# Problem while fetching response using ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I am not getting response while fetching result from my code using AJAX. while sending parameters to file my code is working good... that is, sending parameters to file , as I have  checked using alert msg..
but my php file is not showing any response.

AJAX CODE.

```
function viewsg(){

document.getElementById('sgwaitingmsg').innerHTML = "Just a second...";
var childid = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('childsgselect').value);
var parameters ='childid=' + childid;
http.open('POST', 'fetchsg.php', true);
http.send(parameters);
//alert(parameters);
http.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200 )
    {
    document.getElementById("sgwaitingmsg").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
}
```

PHP CODE.

```
<?php
//$_REQUEST["childid"];
//$_REQUEST["nocache"];
echo $_REQUEST["childid"];
?>
```

HTML CODE.

```
<label id="sgwaitingmsg"></label>
<select id="childsgselect" onchange="viewsg()" >
<option value="">Select Child</option>
<?php while($result=mysql_fetch_assoc($child)){print '<option value="'.$result["snum"].'">'.$result["sfname"].'</option>'; }?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_REQUEST["childid"];` does not do anything. try

```
echo $_POST["childid"];
```

instead

and you have syntax error in your code

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && )
```

should be

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
```

Try this one http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/904ed/10

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['childid'])){ 
    echo $_POST['childid']; 
    die(); 
}  
?> 
<div id="sgwaitingmsg"></div> 
<input id="childsgselect" value="hellllo" /> 
<script> 
function viewsg(){ 

document.getElementById('sgwaitingmsg').innerHTML = "Just a second..."; 
var childid = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('childsgselect').value); 
var parameters ='childid=' + childid; 
var params ='childid=' + childid; 
http=new XMLHttpRequest(); 
http.open('POST', '<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>', true); 
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length); 
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close"); 
http.send(parameters); 
//alert(parameters); 
http.onreadystatechange = function(){ 
      if (http.readyState==4) 
    { 
    document.getElementById("sgwaitingmsg").innerHTML=http.responseText; 
        } 
    } 
} 
viewsg(); 
</script>
```

is fully working script. You'll have to go through

Comment: Its same ,, not fetching response text.

Comment: @user921300: you've got sytnax error in your JS. Look at my edit

Comment: @that I have already tried `if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)` with that. but thats also not working.

Comment: @user921300: look at my edit. you had some important problems there

Comment: @user921300: I can't. You need at least 20 reputation

Comment: Than how can I show you my HTML code. I think my ajax and php code is similar to you but unluckily not giving me output. Wait let me edit on my question my htlm code.

Comment: @RahulSingh: Make sure option got value

Comment: My `http.send` function before `//alert(parameters);` doing as I ahve checked using alert. but don't know reason Y `http.onreadystatechange = function(){` not working.

Comment: it works for me. Copy-paste my work and try it on your machine

Comment: 1. `xmlhttp` was not defined. 2. I have added 3 headers (`http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length); 
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close"); `) 3. You forgot to init your http variable (`http=new XMLHttpRequest(); 
`)

Comment: Ohhh Got it... I have initialize as http and using `xmlhttp.readyState==4` instead of `http.readyState==4`.. got it...

`http.setRequestHeader` Whats need of these headers? I am new with Ajax.

Comment: That first tells to recognize it as a form and these next ones are just making it more clear. You should only use one variable - http or only xmlhttp !